# TypeConverters not working

Tags: android, database, typeconverter

I have problem with my type converter. I added annotation TypeConverters to my field but I still have error that Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. I dont known why.

My Entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(tableName = "drinking")
public class Drinking {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    String date;
    int duration;

    @TypeConverters(DrinkingTypeConverter.class)
    List<AlcoholPageDTO> alcoholList = new ArrayList<>();


    public Drinking(String date, int duration, List<AlcoholPageDTO> alcoholList) {

        this.duration = duration;
        this.date = date;
        this.alcoholList.addAll(alcoholList);
    }
}
```

AlcoholPageDTO class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class AlcoholPageDTO {

    private Alcohol alcohol;
    private int shots;
    private float alcoholAmount;
    List<Long> shootsTime;
}
```

converter

```
public class DrinkingTypeConverter {

    private static Gson gson = new Gson();

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<Drinking> stringToDrinkingList(String data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Drinking>>() {}.getType();

        return gson.fromJson(data, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String drinkingListToString(List<Drinking> someObjects) {
        return gson.toJson(someObjects);
    }
}
```

Database class

```
@Database(entities = {Alcohol.class, Drinking.class}, version = 2)
@TypeConverters({DrinkingTypeConverter.class})
public abstract class ShotCounterDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract AlcoholDao alcoholDao();
    public abstract DrinkingDao drinkingDao();

    private static ShotCounterDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static ShotCounterDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (ShotCounterDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            ShotCounterDatabase.class, "Shot_Counter_Database")
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bring yr @TypeConverters on top of your class name.

This is because your type converter is targeting the list of class `Drinking`, not the list of `AlcoholPageDTO`.

The location of @TypeConverters determine which part of the class will receive the functionality. 
For eg. If it's above a method name, only that method will get convert into different type accordingly.

In your case, you should make TypeConverter from `List<AlcoholPageDTO>` to `String` and vice versa. Then it should fix the problem.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Convert from AlcoholPageDTO to String. 
Not Drinking to String

Comment: @MichałWoźniak if this answer helped you then you can accept it by clicking on a check button beside it :)